# NullPointerException... Why?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Please, Help me...

```
public class TestActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
/********/
            mTestPref = findPreference("test_preference");
            mTestPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {

       @Override
       public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String Message = mMessagePref.getSummary().toString();

        MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
        main.execute(Message);

        return true;
       }
     });
    }

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /************/

     public void execute(String message) {

      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // NullPointerExcepiton
     }
    }

11-04 16:50:12.317: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19524): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
11-04 16:50:12.356: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19524): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-04 16:50:12.356: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19524):     at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:89)
```

Comment: You attempted to use `null`. If `Toast` is a library, you may have sent it `null` as one of the arguments. Are you sure it was cause by the posted lines?

Comment: What are the values for getBaseContext(), message, and Toast.LENGTH_SHORT?  That should tell you, hopefully, what's going on.

Comment: This is about Android, so please tag it as such. (Did that for you this time.)

Comment: ...or `makeText` returns `null`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't use `getBaseContext`. An Activity is a context. Just use `this`.
2. Verify that the string you're using is not null.
3. You don't create Activity objects yourself. You need to have the operating system do that via `startActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Main Activity is created by you, the base context is not set. Maybe you can add:

```
main.setBaseContext(this);
```

before

```
main.execute(Message);
```

But your whole program looks weird. Why do you need to create an activity to execute something? If you need to start another activity, then use startActivity(). If you need it to execute something immediately, you should pass those 'parameters' via the Intent.

Comment: I don't think creating an Activity yourself is going to work. Besides, even if the base context was set, it would still be completely uninitialized. I would assume that it takes more than just calling the constructor to make a context work.

Answer (score 0):

You CAN'T just call new MyActivity(). That's not how activites are created. You can NEVER, EVER call new on a class that extends Activity.

You can't call instance methods of Activites from other classes.